# Replacing a method with only particular types of parameter in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In the code I'm debugging right now, I see the append method for Stringbuilder being called repeatedly.

I want to replace all occurennces of append which are passed any String arguments `append(String str)` by `append(Mycustomfunction(String str))`

Also append can take multiple types of arguments, but I just want to change those which have a String argument.

Anyway to do this more efficiently then inserting this line manually at 1000+ occurences?

EDIT : Adding an example
Example

```
a.append("My Name")
a.append(result.getString("something"))
a.append(2)
a.append(true)
```

I want to change the first two occurences only to

```
a.append(Myfunction("My Name"));
a.append(Myfunction(result.getString("something")));
a.append(2);
a.append(true);
```

Comment: normal copy/replaceAll should help, isnt?

Comment: edited to explain better. How can copy/replaceAll work?

Comment: added the replace commands for ur need in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replace functionality(Ctrl+F) of eclipse?
And click the regex checkbox, then define the appropriate regular expression in the find textbox.

Comment: how would regex indetify the type of the argument. Can you suggest a sample regex which can do it?

Comment: [link](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/09/some-useful-regular-expressions-for.html)
Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 replace commands

1) replace `a.append("` with `a.append(Myfunction("`

2) replace `a.append(result.getString` with `a.append(Myfunction(result.getString(`

Comment: how about the closing bracket? Don't we need it to?